# Strip spaces from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like

```
[('Parrish', 'Alabama'), ('Phil Campbell', 'Alabama'), ('Lisman', 'Alabama')]
```

I wanted to strip off the spaces and i wanted the output to be in the form of

```
['Parrish,Alabama','PhilCampbell,Alabama','Lisman,Alabama']
```

Also i have a list like this below, how to split the second element in list

```
['28/08/17','Parrish,Alabama', '33.7306642', '-87.2844473', ' Ground Snow Load is10 psf']
```

My output should be in the form of

```
['28/08/17','Parrish', 'Alabama', '33.7306642', '-87.2844473', ' Ground Snow Load is10 psf']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version 3**

You can use a list comprehension with `','.join`. Use `str.replace` to remove spaces after the join is complete.

```
In [86]: [','.join(y).replace(' ', '')  for y in lst]
Out[86]: ['Parrish,Alabama', 'PhilCampbell,Alabama', 'Lisman,Alabama']
```

Readability improved thanks to [no1xsyzy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912319/how-to-strip-spaces-in-tuple-using-python/45912344?noredirect=1#comment78783368_45912344) and [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912319/how-to-strip-spaces-in-tuple-using-python/45912344?noredirect=1#comment78783639_45912344).

Comment: I think using generator comprehension instead of `map` will be more readable. (parens confusing)

Comment: @no1xsyzy Point taken. Thanks.

Comment: I might even be tempted to remove the nested comp and do `[','.join(tup).replace(' ', '') for tup in lst]`...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the suggestions, as always!

Comment: Also i have a list like this below, how to split the second element from the list

['28/08/17','Parrish,Alabama', '33.7306642', '-87.2844473', ' Ground Snow Load is1']  My output should be in the form of

['28/08/17','Parrish', 'Alabama', '33.7306642', '-87.2844473', ' Ground Snow Load  is1']

Comment: @ppriyanka that'd be `somevar = [el for word in your_list for el in word.split(',')]` so I wouldn't ask a new question as coldspeed suggests as it'd be a dupe of how to flatten something in some way.

Comment: @Jon Clements can you  explain the line of code which you have wrote.

Comment: I'll let @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ do that if they want... :)

Comment: @ppriyanka `word.split(',')` returns a list in the outer loop, and you use the inner loop to iterate over each item in that list.